# How to overcome the heapdump created by Vaadin ScssCache?

Tags: java, sass, vaadin, heap-memory, heap-dump

I have created an application using `Vaadin` having respective UI.

I am running in a server with having a maximum heapload of 250 Mb. The application gets crashed because of the heapload since it is not garbage collected.

I tried to run with a `visualVM` analyzer. Found to have lot of instances and somehow the vaadin ScssCache is making this mess.

How can I rectify this error? Is it because of the browser cache settings or should I do something with the vaadinservletcache entry?

I really do not understand please help. I have attached my VisualVm screen shot for the reference. Thank you very much. I am using vaadin 7.6.3.

[image: visualVm]

Comment: It holds 1.2MB with the effective CSS to deliver to each client on startup.  What error do you think is happening here?  Is your application/vaadin servlet running in production mode?

Comment: Yes it is running in a production mode. It works fine for couple of minutes and latter it gradually increases and the garbage collector doesn't clear it.

Comment: So this screenshot is done at the beginning?  To what extend does this cache grows before the application dumps core?

Answer (score 0):

The attached VisualVM screenshot shows that the entire `scssCache` retains 1248kb of memory, out of which 1200kb is used for the actual cached CSS contents. This is less than 1% of your 250mb heap size and most likely not the problem.

That 1200kb `char[]` with the compiled CSS might be the biggest individual object on the heap, but there's only one such object. You will thus have to look for something else that consumes lots of memory. I'd recommend looking at the list of Classes sorted by their retained size, and ignore low-level classes such as `char[]`, `java.lang.String` or `java.Util.HashMap` and instead try to pinpoint anything related to your own application.

I would also encourage you to verify that your application is actually running in production mode since the only code path that I can identify that does anything with `scssCache` is through `VaadinServlet.serveOnTheFlyCompiledScss` which checks whether production mode is enabled and in that case returns before touching the cache.